# post to facebook page with photos

Tags: php, facebook

We have been developing server program written in PHP which post some information to Facebook Page periodically. It runs on Linux server as a daemon.

At first, we tried to post information to personal Facebook wall. Sometime there are some photos, so we create album to upload more than two photos.

This works fine. So, we tried to post to Facebook Page.

Then, we met some trouble.

Text only information can be posted correctly. But when we post with a photo, Facebook Page shows as attachment file. And it shows posted from personal account not from application.

In case of more than two photos, album creation fails as error(Invalid ID for album owner).

Our code is as follows,

```
$album = $facebook->api('/' . $id . '/albums','POST',array("name" => 'xxxx'........);
```

This works fine in case of personal Facebook wall.

Please advice for us.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try first with Graph API explorer of FB, should be something like

```
$album = $facebook->api('/' . $id . '/photos','POST',array("message" => 'your text here'........);
```

Comment: I tried as same as your answer when only one photo. It was executed successfully, but it's photo appears on Facebook Page as attached document. It can be seen as a photo in case of personal Facebook wall.

Comment: please show the entire post request to facebook, not only the call to this library. In case of uploading a photo, you actually need to upload the entire graphics bitstream, not only an external URL if you want FB to hold the photo and not only an "attachement"

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot post entire code because of character length. In case of one photo, we code as follows. $facebook->setFileUploadSupport(true);
$ret = $facebook->api('/' . $id . '/photos/', 'POST', array(
'image' => '@' . $filespec,
'name' => $postMsg,
'access_token' => $accessToken)
);

Comment: and what is in $filespec?

Comment: You should read this: [create photos]https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page/#photos

Comment: For example, $filespec = '/var/photo/sample.jpg';  It works fine when we post to personal Facebook wall. We want to know is difference between personal Facebook wall from Facebook Page. Thanks.